# Vue, I have used $mount() on a component, is there a way to $unmount() a reference?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I realise this is not how the framework was originally intended to be used.
What I'd like to do is programatically mount a component to the page, then programmatically unmount it.

```
const Component = Vue.extend({
    template: '<div>This works</div>'
})
const c = new Component()
c.$mount()
document.getElementById('app').appendChild(c.$el)
```

What I'd like to do from here is clean up the component

```
c.$unmount()
c.$destroy()
```

Is there something like this that will remove the listeners and perform a full cleanup?

Or can I simply do the following without consequence

```
document.getElementById('#app').innerHTML = ''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `$mount` on a new DOM element, append `component.$el` to `#app` and remove it after `$destroy`.

```js
const component = new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      message: "Hello"
    }
  },
  template: "<p>{{message}}<p>",
});

const app = document.getElementById("app");

// Mounting on a empty div created programatically
component.$mount(document.createElement("div"));
app.appendChild(component.$el);

setInterval(() => component.message = "Hello " + Date.now(), 100);

setTimeout(() => {
  // destroying the component and removing it from DOM
  component.$destroy();
  app.removeChild(component.$el); 
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Note for others, in Vue3, $destroy has been removed from the API. https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/introduction.html#removed-apis